# select with $('#id ul li') & excluding .class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using the following code in a function.

```
$('#id ul li').css('background-image','none');
```

Is it possible to add a unless statement so it excludes any li with the class .class ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not an "unless" statement, but a `:not()` statement:

```
$('#id ul li:not(.class)').css('background-image', 'none');
```